# Get Bounding Box Lenght Of Curved Road

Tags: mathematics

Ok so I got this curved block [image]

And I want to calculate it's **exact** length using bounding box. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: maybe manually calculate the difference, between x_min and x_max, y_min and y_max, z_min and z_max of your mesh?

Comment: Umm, english please..

Comment: such as: http://imgur.com/gallery/Yu9Vm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the object and press <kbd>N</kbd>. The properties panel on the right will open. In the panel, search for dimensions under scale. In dimensions you will find the bounding box size.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Measureit addon
[image]
For more details watch this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=crMAa5tG-l8
To download : https://github.com/Antonioya/blender/blob/40b63abde362555d0cf3cfb00454f0691871f144/measureit/measureit_v1_6_7.zip